# date time sorting in chronological order in linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Below is my code , i want to see the appointments in chronological order like in descending order but ascending time like:

unable to achieve this can anyone help me out

List appointments = _diagnosticRepo.GetFacilityAppointmentsReportVersion(FacilityID).Where(x => x.Status != AppointmentRescheduledID)
.ToList();

i want to see the appointments in chronological order like in descending order but ascending time like, and the appointmentdate is coming on Date variable and time on Time variable so how do i achieve this

for eg. if a appointment is made for the same date with different time then time should be in ascending for the appointments order

*appointment 1   06-07-2019 10:00Am
*appointment 2 06-07-2019 11:00 AM
*appointment 3 05-07-2019 10:00 pm

Comment: What you describe is not descending order. 6 @ 10 am, 6 @ 11 am (going up), 5 @ 10 pm( going down). You can only order by real order so either 6-11, 6-10,5-10 OR 5-10,6-10,6-11

Comment: What you ask for isn't chronological order. It's two different orders based on the same field. In SQL you'd have to extract the date and time part and order by each one separately, ie `ORDER BY cast(appointmentDT as date) desc, cast(appointmentDT as time) asc`

Comment: order desc by `DateTime.Date` the asc by `DateTime.TimeOfDay`

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.AppointmentDateTime.Date).ThenBy(x => x.AppointmentDateTime.TimeOfDay)` maybe?

Comment: If you want different order directions you should probably *store* the date and time separately and index them. This would also make filtering by date faster

Comment: If a particular answer helped you, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You must first ensure the thing you're ordering is a DateTime and not a string. Strings do not sort properly in this case.

```
List<DiagnosticPatientAppointmentModel> appointments = _diagnosticRepo
    .GetFacilityAppointmentsReportVersion(FacilityID)
    .Where(x => x.Status != AppointmentRescheduledID)
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(a => DateTime.Parse(a.ScheduledTime).Date)
    .ThenBy(a => DateTime.Parse(a.ScheduledTime).Time);
```

Here is a working example:

```
new List<dynamic> {
    new { ScheduledTime = "6/7/2019 11:45 PM" },
    new { ScheduledTime = "6/7/2019 10:45 PM" },
    new { ScheduledTime = "6/6/2019 9:45 PM" }
}
.OrderByDescending(a => DateTime.Parse(a.ScheduledTime).Date)
.ThenBy(a => DateTime.Parse(a.ScheduledTime).TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run this in dotnetfiddle and it seems fine:

```
    DateTime[] dates = new  DateTime[] { 
       DateTime.Parse("06-07-2019 10:00AM"),
       DateTime.Parse("06-07-2019 11:00AM"),
       DateTime.Parse("05-07-2019 10:00 pm")
    };

    foreach(var d in dates.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.TimeOfDay))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm"));
    }
```

It produces the following output:

07 May 2019 10:00

07 Jun 2019 10:00

07 Jun 2019 11:00

Comment: Note OPs requirement - first ordering should be OrderByDescending for date

Answer (score -5):

Try following :

```
            DateTime[] dates = new  DateTime[] { 
                DateTime.Parse("06-07-2019 10:00AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("06-07-2019 11:00AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("05-07-2019 10:00 pm")
            };

            DateTime[] orderDates = dates
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.TimeOfDay))
                .ToArray();
```

---

This should work also

```
            DateTime[] orderDates2 = dates
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                .ThenBy(x => x.TimeOfDay)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are downvoted less often than those which simply say "Try this" and the code.

Comment: Why would you group the entries?

Comment: The OP want dates decreasing and time increasing for each day.  Groupby is only way.  If you didn't try to get a better answer than do not give negative points.

Comment: no groupby isnt the only way it simply worked by   List<DiagnosticPatientAppointmentModel> appointments = _diagnosticRepo .GetFacilityAppointmentsReportVersion(FacilityID) .Where(x => x.Status != AppointmentRescheduledID) .ToList().OrderbyDescending(x=> x.Date).ThenBy(x=>x.Time);